# How do I create a two-column table in React with vertical headers?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Desired Outcome

[image: Desired Outcome]

I'd like to build a two column table with the headings (name, email, phone, etc.) displayed vertically. Currently, if I were to use the table in Material UI, the headings are displayed in one horizontally. I'm very new to React- how can I achieve the desired image?

Comment: Looks like a definition list to me https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in reactjs with material ui, it's going to be something like this!

[image]

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.row-style {
  background-color: #D7D3D3;  
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid white 5px;
}
```

```html
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import './App.css';


const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {  
    width:650,
  },
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='table-container'>
      <Table  className={classes.table} >      
          <TableRow  className='row-style'>
              <TableCell variant="head">Full Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Cell 1</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Cell 2</TableCell>
          </TableRow>     
          <TableRow  className='row-style'>
              <TableCell variant="head">Email</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Cell 1</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Cell 2</TableCell>
          </TableRow>       
      </Table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called Table with header cells in the first column only. https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/one-header/#table-with-header-cells-in-the-first-column-only

I am not sure about material ui table, but this is example with plain html table.

EXAMPLE:
Concerts:

[image]

CODE SNIPPET:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <td>12 February</td>
        <td>24 March</td>
        <td>14 April</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Event</th>
        <td>Waltz with Strauss</td>
        <td>The Obelisks</td>
        <td>The What</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <td>Main Hall</td>
        <td>West Wing</td>
        <td>Main Hall</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```